# Access denied: Unable to set private key permissions

Tags: server, windows-server-2008-r2, private-key

On our Windows Web Server 2008 R2, we are hitting 'access denied' errors when we try to update permissions on a RSA private key file.

Even from an **elevated** powershell of an admin, this fails:

```
$fullpath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\......."
$uname = "\network service"
icacls $fullpath /grant $uname`:RX
```

Error:

```
Access denied.
```

What local-policy permissions are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. We first needed to take ownership of the file.

```
takeown /F <filename>
```